# If the transitive closures of two sets are equal can they be disjoint?

Tags: set-theory

I came across a problem today that I can't get out of my head: if $\mathcal{TC}(A)=\mathcal{TC}(B)$, can $A$ and $B$ be disjoint? My guess is no, but I can't quite show it. A direct proof seems unsuccessful, while a proof by contradiction going such as suppose $A$ and $B$ disjoint and $\mathcal{TC}(A)=\mathcal{TC}(B)$ gives a hypothesis that is difficult to work with. Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $A=\{0,2,4,6,8,\cdots\}$ and $B=\{1,3,5,7,9,\cdots\}$. It is obvious that $A\cap B$ is empty. However the transitive closure of $A$ and $B$ are $\omega$.